# Add indication that a user is question banned to mod info on user profiles

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, moderator-tools, post-ban

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Include user being blocked from posting in user history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98905/include-user-being-blocked-from-posting-in-user-history)

The moderator tools don't tell us if a user has been automatically question-banned by the system.

It may well be that the question ban is enough of an incentive to the user to do better, so why pile on a suspension?

The present mod tools don't help us make that informed decision so we often end up suspending an already question-banned user which seems pretty heavy handed and just adds insult to injury.

This question is related but was asked as a feature for general community consumption which is not what I'm asking for:

[Show some indication that account is banned from asking new questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89084/show-some-indication-that-account-is-banned-from-asking-new-questions)

Comment: As an aside: do all moderators know that automatic *answer* bans exist too?

Comment: @Arjan - We get no data on that either.

Comment: Hehe, I actually meant: did you know *the feature was introduced*? ;-)

Comment: @Arjan - ah ok :). Yes we know about that feature.